# How to look up field name from an aggregate result

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to look up the index or name of a data frame based on the maximum of the aggrate values of that data frame, for example:

```
df <- data.frame(
        id = 1:6, 
        v1 = c(3, 20, 34, 23, 23, 56),
        v2 = c(1, 3, 4, 10, 30, 40),
        v3 = c(20, 35, 60, 60, 70, 80))

  id v1 v2 v3  
1  1  3  1 20  
2  2 20  3 35  
3  3 34  4 60  
4  4 23 10 60  
5  5 23 30 70  
6  6 56 40 80  

> colSums(as.data.frame(df[[1]]))  
df[[1]]  
     21   

> colSums(as.data.frame(df[[2]]))  
df[[2]]   
    159   

> colSums(as.data.frame(df[[3]]))  
df[[3]]   
     88
```

So for example the maximum result using `colSums` is 159, and I'm trying to figure out how to to return '`df[[2]]`'

Comment: You only have one data.frame here.  What are you trying to get?  The column with the highest sum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can simply run `colSums` directly on your `data.frame`

```
> colSums(df)
 id  v1  v2  v3 
 21 159  88 325
```

Subsetting is easy too

```
> df[which.max(colSums(df))]
  v3
1 20
2 35
3 60
4 60
5 70
6 80
```

Or, if you just want the index, as implied in your first line:

```
> which.max(colSums(df))
v3 
 4
```

Also note that if you expect there might be more than one column with the same maximum sum, and you want to return all of them, you can use `which(colSums(df) == max(colSums(df)))` instead of `which.max`, which only returns the first occurrence.

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what i was looking for, and apologies for the error in the analysis.